How to add / delete markers on click using react-photo-sphere-viewer and the Marker-plugin
Can anyone give me some example code on how to get this to work. I am using Nextjs. The markers are not showing on click.I want user to interact with their 360 images and being able to add markers when clicking on the panorama without having to reload the screen.
"use client";

//Necessary imports
import React, {  useState } from "react";
import { ReactPhotoSphereViewer } from "react-photo-sphere-viewer";
import {
  MarkerConfig,
  MarkersPlugin,
} from "@photo-sphere-viewer/markers-plugin";
import "@photo-sphere-viewer/markers-plugin/index.css";

function App() {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState<MarkerConfig[]>([]);
  const handleClick = (data: any) => {
    setMarkers([
      ...markers,
      {
        // image marker that opens the panel when clicked
        id: "kadjkad",
        position: {
          yaw: data.data.yaw / 0.01746 + "deg",
          pitch: data.data.pitch / 0.01752 + "deg",
        },
        image: "arrow.png",
        anchor: "bottom center",
        size: { width: 50, height: 50 },
        tooltip: "Mountain peak. <b>Click me!</b>",
      },
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ReactPhotoSphereViewer
        src={"./360images/fullres/IMG_1.jpg"}
        plugins={[
          [
            MarkersPlugin,
            {
              markers: markers,
            },
          ],
        ]}
        height={"100vh"}
        width={"100vw"}
        onClick={handleClick}
      ></ReactPhotoSphereViewer>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


You need to call the "addMarker" method on the Markers plugin directly, being a vanilla library is does not react to state changes. There is a complet example in the readme https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-photo-sphere-viewer#calling-plugin-methods-and-handling-events-from-outside-the-component-new
